# Regex : How to match anything after a word or words?

Tags: regex

I need to find and replace all links. But I do not know to use regex codes. I have this link : 
http://sitename.com/FileID/filename.zip

I want to match/find this part : filename.zip

So with this way, I want to make this link like this :

http://sitename.com/FileID/NEWWORD-filename.zip

There are a lot of links and all theirs FileID is different. So I want to match only filename section.

Answer (score 1):

In basic you want to ignore everything till last slash     `http.*\/(.*)`
If you know any rules regarding FileID (for example it's number or string specific length) you can make it more precise, like: `http://sitename.com/983032/filename.zip` -> `http.*\d+\/(.*)`

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it must start with http://sitename.com , because I have other links which starting with another domains.

Comment: Nice use of regex's greediness (although `.*\/(.*)` is even shorter). BTW **backslash** is `\ ` , **slash**  is `/`

Comment: @Yearmaz I hope you've got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

In JS (you can adapt it to any language you use) you can do this like this:

```
var url = 'http://sitename.com/FileID/filename.zip'
var regex = /.*\/(.*)/;

var m = url.match(regex);
console.log(m[1]);
```

Since you need it to start with 'sitename', a new version:

```
var regex = /http:\/\/sitename.com\/[^/]\/(.*)
```

Other possible regex would be:

```
var regex = /[^/]*$/
```

(In this case the complete match will be your filename: 'filename.zip', always matching only the last bit of the url)

PS: Some languages/libraries support also lookbehind, but I believe not all of them do.